# What was the "slight irregularity in the magnetic containment field"?

Tags: big-hero-6

In the movie *Big Hero 6* there is a scene where Krei is performing an experiment to test whether or not teleportation (and potentially time travel) is possible. He called it *Project Silent Sparrow*, which has two portals; the entrance and the exit, such that if an object is sent into the entrance located at some point A in space, then the object is sent out from the exit located at some point B in space. Krei described this as "reinventing the very concept of transportation". The scene is below.

At 1:21, one of the workmen noticed *"a slight irregularity in the magnetic containment field"* which, when the experiment was tested with a human (named Abigail Callahan), brought it all down to a disaster.

Throughout the rest of the movie, it is *never* actually revealed what this slight irregularity actually was. It would have been vital information since Krei says at 0:58, *"Now, we didn't spend billions of tax dollars to teleport hats.*" This meant that the experiment was very very costly, and so it is worth knowing what the slight irregularity actually was. Also, because Abigail never actually teleported *back*, then there is nearly no reason as to why the slight irregularity should be kept a secret.

So what *was* the irregularity? Does anybody have an idea? I found a theory on YouTube that describes what the irregularity might be.

The basic idea is that after the events of the film, Hiro uses *Project Silent Sparrow* to try and go back in time to save Tadashi. *That* is what causes the "slight irregularity". He fails and overshoots, ending up in the past, right after his parents died and before he moved to live in San Fransokyo with his aunt. There he meets his younger self and poses as his older brother, raising him.

Are there any other thoughts, or details that I may have missed from the movie?

Comment: I don't believe it's anything other than a plot device to show that the portals are experimental and that despite detecting a problem, they decided to go ahead anyway instead of doing the smart thing and aborting. That sets the scene for the Professor to blame himself since he should have insisted on checking it out.

Comment: @Valorum But if we view it like that, that's like saying **Toy Story** did not feature Andy's dad because it was too difficult and expensive to animate another human (after trying to animate the Pixar Short, **Geri's Game**). Although my argument might seem like trying to avoid the truth, I would, just for fun, like to pro-pose another possible concept. Nonetheless, the *plot device* as you put it is quite a well-known cliché :)

Comment: @User4777343 - Oh sure. I completely agree that 'meta answers' ("*Because that's how they wrote it"*) aren't suitable as answers. That's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: They have a temporary wormhole (think black-hole) created by electro-gravity.  If it was mass driven, it would eat the solar system.  The lack of stability of part of the balancing act holding it open, when a human-trial and customer-facing-demonstration is happening is a critical decision fail.  They should have run thousands of tests leading up to the "piloted craft inside the bubble" part.